# Permission Issues in Windows 10

Tags: windows, file-permissions, acl

I have 2 machines, one is Windows 10 and the other is Windows 7, recently whenever I download a file on Windows 10 machine directly on my External Hard Disk and detach it from that machine and try to attach it to windows 7 machine, I have no access to any of the downloaded files it gives me access denied. I can access folders and see the files are present but cannot open them.

To solve this issue I have to manually assign permission to each files by first taking ownership of that file for "Everyone" account and then assigning "Everyone" full control.

I have tried to take the ownership of the folder but receives the error of access denied for each files when selecting the option of "Permission Inheritance for files and Sub Folder"

I have even tried to write a PowerShell to assign permission but the situation does not change it returns with an access denied error. FYI, PowerShell window is opened as Administrator by selecting Run as administrator.

Even if I run the intended application as Administrator it will still not work it will still give me Access Denied.

The only workaround I found was to perform the above actions of individual file ownership and permission assignment.

It would of great help is someone can provide a permanent solution to this issue.

BTW, The external hard drive which I use is WD drive and its with me for than 5 year now and never encounter this issue in the past.

And the files in questions are Photos, videos, documents and mp3.

Comment: When you take ownership of the folder, you should mark the option to take ownership of subfolders and files.

Comment: I have tried doing that but it still says access denied.

Answer (score 2):

This is neither a PowerShell nor a programming issue, so the question would be more suitable for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Creating a file on removeable media on one system and then trying to access that same file on a different system will normally fail unless you took precautions to make the data accessible from other systems. That is because even though users and groups may have the same name on both systems they still have different SIDs (which is what the system actually uses to decide whether access is or isn't allowed).

To grant a user on a different system access to the file you have to take ownership and grant the user(s) on that system access.

```
takeown /f x:\ /a /r /d y
icacls x:\ /reset /t /c
icacls x:\ /grant administrators:(oi)(ci)f username:(oi)(ci)rx
```

Note that adjusting ownership and permissions of a single file usually does not suffice. The user must be able to at least traverse the entire path to that file. Similarly taking ownership and adjusting permissions on a folder may not suffice unless the files in that folder inherit their permissions from the folder. If they don't you need to take ownership of the files and adjust their permissions as well.

The above 3 commands recursively take ownership of everything on drive X:, reset permissions to enable inheritance, and grant access to the Administrators group (full control) and the user "username" (read and execute).

With that said, you can prepare permissions so that files are accessible on different systems without the need to take ownership and adjusting permissions on the target system. There are a number of principals and groups that have the same [well-known SID](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems) on all Windows systems, e.g.

- Everyone (S-1-1-0)
- Administrators (S-1-5-32-544)
- Users (S-1-5-32-545)
- Authenticated Users (S-1-5-11)

Granting access for instance to the group "Users" should make your data accessible across different systems.

Comment: Regarding direcrtory traversal, standard users have SeChangeNotifyPrivilege enabled by default, which bypasses traverse checking. This privilege may surprise someone who's used to Unix, which requires execute access to traverse a directory.

Comment: I thought I was quite familiar with Windows, but I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Install a separate hard drive or prepare a separate partition for each operating system.

Install the operating systems. For example, if your PC has Windows 8.1, install Windows 10 onto the other hard drive or partition.

Reboot the PC. The boot menus should appear with both operating systems listed.

If both operating systems aren't listed:

Open a command line, either as an administrator from inside Windows, or by booting to a command line using the Windows installation disk and presssing Shift+F10, or by booting to Windows PE (WinPE: Create USB Bootable drive).

Add boot options for a Windows operating system.

Bcdboot D:\Windows

Reboot the PC. Now, the boot menu will show both menu options.

Comment: These are two different Computer and not partition.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s give permission to the file and check if that helps. Follow these steps to give permission to the drive.

1. Right-click on the file which you’re unable to access and select Properties.
2. Click on the ‘**Security**’ tab and under ‘**Group or user names**’ click on ‘**Edit**’.
3. Click on ‘**Add**’ and type ‘**everyone**’.
4. Click on ‘**Check names**’ and then click ‘**OK**’.
5. Select ‘**everyone**’ and under ‘**Allow**’ select ‘**Full control**’ and click
   on ‘**Apply**’ and Click ‘**Ok**’.

Hope this helps.